# Why is the SliverAppBar of the CustomScrollView displayed below the elements of the SliverList When shrinkWrap is true?

Tags: flutter, shrinkwrap, customscrollview

Normally, a floating SliverAppBar will be displayed on the upper layer of the SliverList as we slide the SliverList down.Like this :

[image]

But, when change the value of `shrinkWrap` to `true`, the `SliverAppBar` is displayed below the elements of the `SliverList` or `SliverGrid`.

[image]

How to resolve this problem?

here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return CustomScrollView(
      shrinkWrap: false,
      slivers: <Widget>[

        const SliverAppBar(
          pinned: false,
          floating: true,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text('SliverAPPBar'),
          ),
        ),

        SliverGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 150.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 150.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 150.0),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 150.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              child: Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),


        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 100.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 100.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 100.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 100.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 100.0),
              ),
            ],

          ),
        ),


        SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 150.0,
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 150.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 150.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 150.0),
              ),

              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 150.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                child: Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );


  }
}
```

Comment: A few hours ago, I added an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28197) about this on Flutter's codebase.